# Adding style to Blazor dropdown menu option

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have this User Menu option dropdown which is highlighting each option when you keep the cursor over it. Somehow the highlight is going out of menu option. I am missing out on some CSS here i guess. Please help.

```
         <BSDropdown DropdownDirection="DropdownDirection.Left">
            <BSDropdownToggle Color="Color.Light"><img id="Logo" src="/images/avatar.png" 
            alt="" style="width:25px" /></BSDropdownToggle>
            <BSDropdownMenu>
              <BSDropdownItem @onclick="@menuButtonClick1" >Manage Users</BSDropdownItem>
              <BSDropdownItem @onclick="@menuButton_DoLogout">Logout</BSDropdownItem>
            </BSDropdownMenu>            
          </BSDropdown>
```

Attaching the image here:
[image: Current output]

UPDATE:
I am attaching css code i am seeing in chrome inspect.   `white-space: nowrap;` has been cancelled in the css side. I added this again in app.css as important. Still same issue. Any help here?

```
.dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
```

[image: chrome]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using [BlazorStrap](https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStrap)? If so, did you follow the [WebAssembly install instructions](https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStrap#blazor-webassembly-client-side-blazor)?

> Blazor WebAssembly (Client-side Blazor)
>
> Inside the `<head>` element of your `wwwroot/index.html`, add `<script src="_content/BlazorStrap/blazorStrap.js"></script>`.
> In `Program`, add `builder.Services.AddBootstrapCss();`.

Comment: Yes I am using BlazorStrap. Above mentioned modifications I had added already in my code. Anything else I am missing out?

Comment: You are missing a ```<BSDropdownToggle>``` and closing ```</BSDropdown>``` for your nested dropdown.

Comment: <BSDropdownToggle> is there. I had missed out </BSDropdown> in pasting code here. Edited question. Still issue is there.